# Challenge closed as duplicate that's clearly different

Tags: discussion, policy, close-reasons

I posted [Draw the Olympic Games logo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18986/draw-the-olympic-games-logo), which is clearly a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question requiring users to post a solution that outputs [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art).

[chubakueno](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15171/chubakueno) posted [Olympic Games Logo - Free Style Edition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19050/olympic-games-logo-free-style-edition), which is a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) and has no restrictions on output format. This post has been closed as a duplicate of the above contest.

I cite [Are two questions duplicates if they have different scoring rules?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/are-two-questions-duplicates-if-they-have-different-scoring-rules) and [Duplicate questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/duplicate-questions) on Meta as precedent that these challenges can be considered different; while the posts from my question would be valid answers to the closed question, (currently) the opposite is not true. It's a different challenge with a different goal and much broader restrictions.

I don't have the reputation to cast a reopen vote and get the ball rolling on this, but I believe that the new challenge should be reopened.

Comment: It seems to me, that the _real_ challenge, was to prevent it from being removed. :-P

Answer (score 2):

And now it's been reopened. Thanks!