# Challenge (Solve subset sum quickly if P = NP) incorrectly closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My challenge [Solve Subset-Sum in polynomial time (...if P = NP)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182733/solve-subset-sum-in-polynomial-time-if-p-np) was closed as a duplicate of [Golf the Subset-Sum Problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8655/golf-the-subset-sum-problem). But the [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) aspect of my challenge makes it very different. The main difficulty of my challenge is to succinctly enumerate programs (see the pseudocode I wrote in the linked challenge).

I'm not sure exactly what to do about this, but [precedent](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/898/challenge-closed-as-duplicate-thats-clearly-different) says I should just ask on meta.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the close voters saw the similarities between the two challenges, and interpreted your challenge as a duplicate without reading the finer details that distinguish it from the other challenge. Thankfully, one of our users has reopened the challenge.

I would like to remind close voters to read challenges carefully before voting to close, as an unwarranted closure can be very offputting to new users.