# Should we re-open "Best Yahtzee score"?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/150487/46271) was closed as a dupe of [this other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/score-a-game-of-yahtzee) by the gold [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) vote of Leaky Nun. And yes, I'd agree they're mostly dupes of one another.

However, the newer question is closer to what we'd expect now, and the older version has a more cumbersome I/O format, not to mention only six answers.

[This Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8286/67312) says we should raise a meta question about it, so that's what this is.

(note that I don't care that I already answered the new question)

Comment: I don't want to discourage insightful discussion, but posting a Meta question this quickly might be jumping the gun.  So far only one user has voted to close, that user may be a gold user but its only one user.  We ought to wait until there is a clear tension before bringing it to the meta.  (I also unhammered the question so we'll see)

Comment: @WheatWizard yeah, you're right, I really meant this to be a question about closing the older question as a dupe but my brain appears to not be working any longer.