# What is the stance on challenges that are supersets of other challenges?

Tags: discussion

I have [this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25837/77309) in the Sandbox at time of writing. I want to add some more requirements that can potentially majorly change how some solutions can work (dakuten, handakuten, small kana).

**Should there be 2 challenges with one a superset of the other, or just one challenge with the new requirements?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you believe (and sandbox reviewers agree) that the two versions are sufficiently distinct according to [Mego's guide to duplicates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8286/78410), it's OK to post them as two separate challenges.

However, we can't judge without seeing the actual draft of the second version. So I'd suggest to post both versions in the sandbox first and get some feedback on their dupe-ness.